# Create list of only nested numbering

Tags: enumerate

I would like to create my own list which consists only nested numbering like this:

```
1.1 AAA
1.2 BBBB
1.3 CCCC
```

When I use

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
\item First section \dotfill 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I get error that \item is missing (of course it is correct, but I do not want to have main number only nested). How to improve this?

Comment: Please clarify what the first "1" in "1.1" stands for: Is it a numeral determined by a higher-level ("parent") enumerated list, is it some (more or less) randomly chosen numeral, is it something that should be hardcoded prefix, or something else still? Please advise.

Comment: The `label*` is of no use here if there is not an `\item` of the parent list (i.e. outer list) so far

Comment: Ok, so I just must use `label=1.` to define point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to nest at all (or writing the list manually)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=1.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
\item First section \dotfill 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]